# Hyperlink across table cells?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, html-table

I am trying to create a hyperlink from two pieces of text split over two cells in a table row.

I am generating my table using PHP to echo out the results from my database to a table.
When it echo's it generates a hyperlink with GET variables at the end which allow the user to visit a page relevant to that information.

The problem is that I can't seem to generate a hyperlink that will go across those table cells, I have looked around the web and there is nothing that says I cannot do this.

As you can see from the screenshot below I am generating a hyperlink inside one table cell but I want the other table cell to have the same hyperlink.

[image]

**Code**

```
while ($row = $db->fetch_assoc($newest))
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>";
                                    echo  "<a href='manager.php?method=view&id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['first_name']." ". $row['second_name']. "</td><td>".$row['company_name']."</a>";
                                echo "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
```

I have a feeling that I will just have to generate two separate hyperlinks for the table cells.

However I am hoping someone here can prove me wrong and save me a few lines of code.

Thanks :)

Comment: thats right two hyper links or use CSS frameworks to generate tables or do some javascript to accomplish that

Comment: can I get some upvoting love, seeing as its a good question? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using native hyperlinks, you will have to create separate  wrappers for each cell.

However, if you want to use JS for linking and redirecting, you could do something like:

```
.....
<tr class="clickable" data-href="http://google.com">
<td>cell-1</td>
<td>cell-2</td>
<td>cell-3</td>
</tr>
....
```

and then:

```
$(function(){
    $('tr.clickable').click(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is nice solution, but what DTD is it valid with?

Comment: If the OP doesn't use it elswhere, introducing a dependency on jQuery for this seems a bit heavy-handed

Answer (score 2):

Simply work around it with JS:

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"location.href='manager.php?method=view&id=".$info.";'\">";
```

Comment: it should be `&amp;` shouldn't it?

Comment: It shouldn't. In an URL inside double quotes in an attribute, you do not want to use HTML entities

Comment: Can you provide a reference? I googled only this http://www.squarefree.com/securitytips/web-developers.html (section about "Avoiding XSS holes") and I don't find it reliable. W3schools have nothing on this for html 4.

Comment: There is no potential for XSS here: Your application constructs this string in a way, that makes it static inside your HTML, no user data involved, only a numeric PHP variable - and this is the context for my former comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to break the table structure (ie. putting the name and the company into one (multi-column) cell), there is IMHO no way other than generating two hyperlinks.

What you might want to do is to use some CSS for a hover effect and some JavaScript to register a user clicked on a cell (which you can, given the structure above, associate with the `tr` element).

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it like this. Try instead:

```
 while ($row = $db->fetch_assoc($newest))
    {
        $url = "manager.php?method=view&id=".$row['id'];
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"" . $url.  "\">" . $row['first_name']." ". $row['second_name']. "</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"" . $url.  "\">" . $row['company_name'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = $db->fetch_assoc($newest))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='manager.php?method=view&id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['first_name']." ". $row['second_name']."</a></td><a href='manager.php?method=view&id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['company_name']."</a><td></td>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```